# http.get() method for displaying list of fileNames in dropdown

Tags: angular-httpclient

I have: DataVisualizationModule, DataVisualizationService, DataVisualizationComponent(parent ) with four child components: three dropown lists and button Save.

1. By clicking on dropdown list  I try to display list of items calling getFilesNames method from DataVisualizationComponent. Do I write this method with httpclient service right ?
2. By selecting one item in dropdown how to  pass info about what I choose to save button (later I want take three chosen items and by clicking SAVE button cal function postSetOfSelectedItems method from DataVisualizationComponent).

Here is what I have tried:

```
export class DataManipulationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  baseUrl: string="api/files";

  getFilesList()Observable<File[]>{
    return this.http.get<File[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }
...}

export class DataManipulationComponent implements OnInit {
  file; File;
  files: File[];
  constructor(public dataManipulationService: DataManipulationService ) { }

  getFilesNames(){
     return this.dataManipulationService.getFilesList().subscribe(
     data=>{this.files=data});    
  }

export class CollapseMenuFileComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() file: File;
  @Input() files; File[];
  constructor() { }
}
```

**DataManiuplation.component.html**

```
<div class="mgr">
  <div class="line"><app-collapse-menu-file></app-collapse-menu-file></div>
  <div class="line"><app-collapse-menu-category></app-collapse-menu-category></div>
  <div class="line"><app-collapse-menu-group></app-collapse-menu-group></div>
  <div class="line"><app-save-button></app-save-button></div>
  <div class="right">
    <app-category-creator></app-category-creator>
    <app-group-creator></app-group-creator>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CollapseMenuFileComponent html**

```
<div>
  <div class="description">
    <label>Choose file:</label>
  </div>
  <select (change)="filterFile($event.target.value)">
    <option value="0">-----None-----</option>
    <option *ngFor="let file of files" value={{summary}}>
      {{file.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is what I tried, BUT my friend, just send me "help like this":

Data Manipulation

```
-get files: http GET api/files, 
responseBody: 
{"fileName": string, "id": long}

-add fileset: http PUT  api/files/{id}
requestBody: {"fileName": string, "id": long, "categoryName":string, "groupName":string}
```

So it seems to me that I am far away from what he suggest 
[image: SNAP]